# Is it safe / possible to use a Windows 7 in a Mac with BootCamp for development?

Tags: windows, macos, bootcamp

The title pretty much sums it up. I would use VS2010 for SilverLight, WPF, Windows Phone 7, etc. I just want to know if there's any compilation problems, or potential bugs you wouldn't see on a PC, or you name it. Just want to make sure before I buy. Thing is I'm thinking about buying both a MacBook pro and a PC Laptop, but if I can get both Windows and MacOS for software development (I would also do iPhone, iPad development) in a single computer that would be just great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Windows (or Linux, or anything else for that matter) in BootCamp is exactly the same as running on a regular PC. The only real difference is that Macs use EFI and has to emulate BIOS, but that pretty much only affects the boot process.

Comment: Ok, so I can be safe by buying the Macbook Pro? I'm doing that today so if it does not work you'll hear from me tomorrow man! =P

Comment: It'll work :)
You should take a look at Parallels Desktop (google it). It allows you to run both operating systems simultaneously.

Comment: Lol, that's too much. I just want to be able to do both in a single computer. I'll still look at it out of curiosity. So ok, I'll buy the macbook today, do all that stuff, and only AFTER it works will your answer be accepted =P. Thanks!

Comment: Parallels isn't nearly as good as VMWare Fusion, which rocks, has been 100% stable for me unlike Parallels. VMWare Fusion is as much better alternative to BootCamp, especially if you have >4GB of RAM.

Comment: I talked to my boss, he said other co-workers have been doing windows development in macs with boot camp, so I'll go with what my company has done. Thanks to everyone who answered this.

Comment: I'm developping under bootcamp since 2 years and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do BootCamp, get something with as much RAM as you can put in it, I have 8GB of RAM in my Mac desktop. Run VMWare Fusion 3, give it a single processor and 2GB of RAM, it runs sweet and fast, and you still have a OSX available at the same time. This is how I do development and testing on different machines and browsers. Even have an Ubuntu instance running with a single processor and 21GB of RAM and still have 5GB left on the OSX side and all of them run like they are the only thing running on the machine.